# If $f:\{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b:0\leq\lambda \leq 1\}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear function, then is it true that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Question: Let $V$ be a real vector space and $a,b\in V$ such that $a\neq b.$
>   If $f:\{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b:0\leq\lambda \leq 1\}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear function, then is it true that $f$ is continuous?

I think it is true.
Since $f$ is linear, it suffices to show that  $f$ is bounded.
Let $M = \max\{|f(a)|,|f(b)|\}.$
Note that 
$$|f(\lambda a +(1-\lambda)b)| = |\lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda) f(b)| \leq \lambda M + (1-\lambda)M = M.$$
So $f$ is bounded.

Is my proof above correct?

Comment: I would be careful, since from what I remember a linear transformation on a vector space is (locally) bounded if and only if it is continuous (I think this is the theorem you are quoting), however the domain of $f$ is not a vector space in this case so I'm not sure if the theorem holds here.

Comment: Is $V$ equipped with a norm? Or is it just a general topological vector space?

Comment: The question has no meaning unless you specify a topology on $V$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\lambda_{x}a+(1-\lambda_{x})b$ and $y=\lambda_{y}a+(1-\lambda_{y})b$ be points in $\operatorname{dom}f$.
Note that
$$
x-y=\left(\lambda_{x}-\lambda_{y}\right)\left(a-b\right).
$$
Suppose $V$ is a normed vector space and that $a\neq b$ (the case of $a=b$ is uninteresting since $\operatorname{dom}f$ becomes a singleton).
By the above,
$$
\left|\lambda_{x}-\lambda_{y}\right|=\frac{\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert }{\left\Vert a-b\right\Vert }.
$$
Moreover,
$$
\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\left|f(x-y)\right|=\left|\lambda_{x}-\lambda_{y}\right|\left|f(a-b)\right|,
$$
and hence $f$ is continuous since $|\lambda_{x}-\lambda_{y}|\rightarrow0$ as $\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert \rightarrow0$.

Comment: But this only works on the subspace generated by $a,b$. In general the assertion cannot be true since *any*, also discontinuous, linear mapping is continuous in *finite dimensional* subspaces.

Comment: Since OP wrote $f : \{\lambda a + (1 - \lambda b) b: 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I assumed $\operatorname{dom}f = \{\lambda a + (1 - \lambda b) b: 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \} \subset \operatorname{span}(a, b)$.